# Updating a matrix plot in matplotlib during for cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am running a simulation and I need to update a plot of a matrix every iteration (or every n iterations for that matter). I am doing the plotting using matplotlib, in particular matshow. I tried replicating the code I saw in other StackOverflow questions but I haven't been successful. Currently the code just produces different windows with the new plots instead of updating the first one. Here's the code so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

#   System variables initialization
N = 50
n_iter = 5
betaJ = 0.40
lattice = np.ones([N, N])
energy = -2*betaJ*N**2
choices = list(range(N))

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()

#   Main cycle
for i in range(0, n_iter):
    #   Pick random spin and calculate energy variation caused by flipping it
    x, y = random.choice(choices), random.choice(choices)
    neighbour_spin_sum = lattice[np.mod(x-1, N), y] + lattice[np.mod(x+1, N), y] + lattice[x, np.mod(y+1, N)] + lattice[x, np.mod(y-1, N)]
    delta_energy = 2*betaJ*(neighbour_spin_sum*lattice[x, y])

    #   If energetically favorable, flip spin
    if delta_energy < 0:
        lattice[x, y] = -lattice[x, y] 

    #   Else flip with some probability
    elif random.uniform(0, 1) <= math.exp(-delta_energy):
        lattice[x, y] = -lattice[x, y] 

    plt.matshow(lattice)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I highly suggest you change n_iter to something more reasonable for this code, else unsuspecting people running this will get 10,000 new windows opened.

Comment: Oops, you're completely right. Changing it now.

Comment: Not a solution to your question directly, but you can try other plotting methods that don't require using matshow. `imshow` might be close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that every time the `plt.matshow()` is called matplotlib creates a new plotting axis. To get around this, define the axis and keep reusing it as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

#   System variables initialization
N = 50
n_iter = 10000
betaJ = 0.40
lattice = np.ones([N, N])
energy = -2 * betaJ * N ** 2
choices = list(range(N))

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()

#   Main cycle
for i in range(0, n_iter):
    #   Pick random spin and calculate energy variation caused by flipping it
    x = random.choice(choices)
    y = random.choice(choices)
    neighbour_spin_sum = lattice[np.mod(x-1, N), y] + lattice[np.mod(x+1, N), y] + lattice[x, np.mod(y+1, N)] + lattice[x, np.mod(y-1, N)]

    delta_energy = 2*betaJ*(neighbour_spin_sum*lattice[x, y])

    #   If energetically favorable, flip spin
    if delta_energy < 0:
        lattice[x, y] = -lattice[x, y] 

    #   Else flip with some probability
    elif random.uniform(0, 1) <= math.exp(-delta_energy):
        lattice[x, y] = -lattice[x, y] 

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.matshow(lattice)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This seems to only work on python 2, any idea why?

Comment: It works for me in python 2.7.11 and 3.4.2 (which is a little out of date) Which version specifically are you looking to use it with?